# can we replace multiple methods of same resource, in sinun.stub

Tags: javascript, chai, sinon

Can we replace multiple methods of same resource in one test case

```
it('should render', () => {
    // first replace
    sinon.stub(DBInstance.getCollection(), 'find').returns({});

    //second replace
    sinon.stub(DBInstance.getCollection(), 'findOne').returns({});
    ...
    ...
});
```

Comment: What do you expect? What did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can stored the resource first and stub it or you can use the resource prototype to stub it.

This is simple check code just for example, because I do not know what module you are using.

```
// File: check.js
class Resource {
  find() { console.log('real find') }
  findOne() { console.log('real findOne') }
};

const check = {
  getCollection: () => {
    return new Resource();
  },
};

module.exports = { check, Resource };
```

This is the test file to show you that you can replace multiple methods of the same resource.

```
// File: check.spec.js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { check, Resource } = require('./check');

describe('stub check', () => {
  it('using stored resource', () => {
    // Store the resource first.
    const collection = check.getCollection();
    // Using the stored resource to stub it.
    sinon.stub(collection, 'find').returns({});
    sinon.stub(collection, 'findOne').returns({});
    expect(collection.find()).to.deep.equal({});
    expect(collection.findOne()).to.deep.equal({});
    sinon.restore();
  });

  it('using prototype resource', () => {
    // Using the prototype resource.
    sinon.stub(Resource.prototype, 'find').returns({});
    sinon.stub(Resource.prototype, 'findOne').returns({});
    expect(check.getCollection().find()).to.deep.equal({});
    expect(check.getCollection().findOne()).to.deep.equal({});
    sinon.restore();
  });
});
```

The result when I run it from terminal:

```
$ npx mocha check.spec.js 


  stub check
    ✓ using stored resource
    ✓ using prototype resource


  2 passing (4ms)
```

Not one real method get called.